# Don't Keyboard dismiss on isSecureEntry toggle of UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm using following UItextfield extension to toggle.

```
extension UITextField {
fileprivate func setPasswordToggleImage(_ button: UIButton) {
    if(isSecureTextEntry){
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "eye_circle"), for: .normal)
    }else{
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "eye-off"), for: .normal)

    }
}

func enablePasswordToggle(){
    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    setPasswordToggleImage(button)
    button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -16, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(self.frame.size.width - 25), y: CGFloat(5), width: CGFloat(25), height: CGFloat(25))
    button.tintColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.5)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.togglePasswordView), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.rightView = button
    self.rightViewMode = .always
}
@objc func togglePasswordView(_ sender: Any) {
    self.isSecureTextEntry = !self.isSecureTextEntry
    setPasswordToggleImage(sender as! UIButton)
}
}
```

When I try to toggle password while the keyboard is on, it is dismissing the keyboard and not toggling the password textField.

```
passwordTextField.enablePasswordToggle()
```

this is how I'm using the toggle function. I also have one function defined to dismiss the keyboard when tapping outside the textfields.

```
func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard))
tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

@objc func dismissKeyboard() {
 view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that when the toggle button is pressed, the text field loses it's focus. So this should help:

```
@objc func togglePasswordView(_ sender: Any) {
    self.isSecureTextEntry = !self.isSecureTextEntry
    setPasswordToggleImage(sender as! UIButton)
    self.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```